# Parse HTML string to HTML DOM element using Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, html-parsing, html-sanitizing

I am using Node.js to sanitize through some HTML elements using the cheerio module. I am trying to utilize the module so that I can parse tags into DOM elements. What I would like to be able to do is enter in text into a textarea field for a form and when I add HTML elements as a string inside the textarea, I would like for that HTML string to be rendered into an actual DOM element

```
exports.createStore = async (req, res) => {
   req.body.author = req.user._id;
   const store = await new Store(req.body).save();
   const $ = cheerio.load(store.description);
   $(store.description).text();
   console.log($(store.description).text());
   await store.save();
   req.flash(
      "success",
      `Successfully Created ${store.name}. Care to leave a review?`
   );
   res.redirect(`/store/${store.slug}`);
};
```

Where store.description = 'Hello < b>World< /b>'

I would like store.description to equal Hello **World**

Comment: Have you taken a look at [cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org)?

Comment: No I haven't yet. Doesn't it get the same code from HTMLparser2? What's so special about cheerio?